# 64 bit Windows fails to install but 32 Windows installs fine

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, windows-installation

I've just built a new PC with a Radeon 2600x processor (so it should support 64 bit). I bought a Windows 10 USB installer and plugged it into my PC.
When I run the 64 bit set up to load the files I get the following error:

> The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required file is missing or contains errors
>   File: \windows\system32\boot\winload.exe
>   Status: 0xc0000098

Yet when I run the 32 bit set up it loads and checks the files fine and comes up with the GUI for installing asking me for the language etc. I've not gone any farther because I obviously don't want to install 32 bit Windows.

Comment: how did you create the install USB?

Comment: Try another flash drive. The error could very well be correct that your install media is corrupt.

Comment: @keltari I bought an official Windows 10 Home USB stick /installation media pack from Currys/PC world, a UK retailer.

Comment: How much RAM do you have? Double check the right amount of RAM is showing up in the BIOS/UEFI settings. Test the RAM with memtest.

Comment: @falkon13 Does it claim it’s a 32-bit or 64-bit image?

Comment: Check the UEFI to ensure it's 64-bit and all relevant settings are correct. What are your motherboard and UEFI versions?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Yeah seems that was the issue, bit annoying as it was official Microsoft merchandise, bought a new USB and downloaded the installation stuff and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

So it seems the USB I had bought was corrupted. So I bought a new USB and added the Windows 10 installation tool on it.

Comment: You may wish to demand some recompense from the retailer, or if they refuse, let Microsoft know that a reseller is dispensing defective products with their name.

Comment: Might be caused by the corruption of ISO image file in this USB disk. We could check if the USB  ISO image works well as a bootable USB disk after copy the contains to another USB.